# ElasticSearch not running on raspberry pi

Tags: java, elasticsearch, raspberry-pi, kibana

I am trying to install and run elasticsearch on my raspberry pi and when I execute the command `sudo service elasticsearch restart` I don't see elasticsearch running and when I check the status using the command `sudo service elasticsearch status` I see the below response

```
Dec 28 23:15:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts elasticsearch...
Dec 28 23:15:32 raspberrypi elasticsearch[21031]: [warning] /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: JVM flavor 'sun6' not understood
Dec 28 23:15:32 raspberrypi elasticsearch[21031]: [warning] /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: No java runtime was found
Dec 28 23:15:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts elasticsearch.
```

I have below java version installed on my raspberry pi

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1, mixed mode)
```

Not sure if the issue is with Java version or elasticsearch version . Also on hitting curl localhost:9200 I get connection refused error. And on executing below `./bin/elasticsearch --version` I receive the error

```
root@raspberrypi:/usr/share/elasticsearch# ./bin/elasticsearch --version
Option requires an argument: '--version'.
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Note : I am using Java 11 , is that a issue ?

Comment: As I recall, the elastic search command you're running looks at a number of environment variables such as `$JAVA_HOME` and `$ES_JAVA_HOME` to determine where the JRE directory is. Could it be that these environment variables are not defined?

Comment: more ~/.bashrc , 
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Comment: root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# echo $JAVA_HOME
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf`